# VirtualBox 6.1x: How enable 'Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V' to enable 'KVM virtualization'?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm

Using `VirtualBox` **6.1.36** - in 2 different laptops with Windows 7 and 10 **Home** - the guest is `Ubuntu Desktop` **20.04** - I have the following situation about Docker:

- [Docker Desktop remains stopped on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 through VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420908/docker-desktop-remains-stopped-on-ubuntu-desktop-20-04-through-virtualbox)

Seems the situation is related with `KVM Virtualization` - now according with:

- [Install Docker Desktop on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/)

In the *KVM virtualization support* sub-section indicates execute some commands, so was executed

```
sudo modprobe kvm
 # shows nothing

sudo modprobe kvm_intel
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported

sudo kvm-ok
 INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
 KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Therefore, theoretically according with this link is possible do nested virtualization within VirtualBox

- [[feature-request] Nested Virtualization: VT-in-VT](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)

Now in the two hosts I have the following issue:

[image]

How you can see the `Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V` checkbox is disabled, it happens even if the `Enable PAE/NX` checkbox is checked

**Question**

- How enable `Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V` to enable `KVM virtualization`?

Comment: Taking the error message that your processor does not support it, then what you want is impossible due an incapability with your hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `VirtualBox` closed, execute

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VirtualMachineName> --nested-hw-virt on
```

Source

- [Virtualbox enable nested vtx/amd-v greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56973830/3665178)

Therefore currently is only possible through command and not by the GUI itself.